# How do I perform a whitespace-insensitive search-and-replace in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have some s-expressions upon which I'd like to perform a search-and-replace.  However, the s-expressions are printed with varying levels of indentation.  This indentation means that searching by a string that I paste in won't match.

I could setup a regular expression that replaces current whitespace characters with the regex whitespace wildcard.  But, I'd prefer to just set a flag that enables whitespace-insensitive matching, similar to how we can enable case-insensitive matching.  Does anyone know of such a flag or how to do that?

Suppose for whatever reason I have an s-expression that's formatted as (after all, this is a contrived example that represents the actual problem):

```
(foo 1 2 3
   (bar 4 5
     (baz 4))
 (bar 4 5
   (baz 4)))
```

I'd like to be able to do a whitespace-insensitive search for the following and replace it with `x` (which result in replacing both of the above occurences with `x`:

```
(bar 4 5
   (baz 4))
```

Comment: Could you give a small example of what you mean? I'm not sure I get what's to be replaced and what is to be preserved.  FWIW, `replace-lax-whitespace` might come in useful here.

Comment: `search-lax-whitespace` or `replace-lax-whitespace` looks like what I need.  Unfortunately I'm on Emacs 23.1.1, so I'm out of luck, but maybe I can load the elisp manually.

Comment: I was wrong, it won't solve this: The emacs manual on `replace-lax-whitespace`: *This only affects how Emacs finds the text to replace, not the replacement text.*  The people on [Emacs StackExchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com) probably know more than I do, you could try posting this question there.

Comment: Actually, I still think you were right.  I've edited the question to be clearer.